# Windows kernel or user mode crash dumps

Tags: data-request, programming

I am looking for a set of Windows crash dumps (`.dmp` files) that I could use during trainings. This may be user mode crash dumps (application crashes, "Send information to Microsoft") or kernel mode crashes (blue screen). They should all contain an unhandled exception to ba analyzed with WinDbg or Visual Studio.

The crash dumps should be available for free and for commercial use.

Ideally they would already have been analyzed, so that one could look up the expected result.